# C++ table alignment - cout and iomanip

Tags: c++, alignment, cout

I have a small alignment issue in my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setw(5) << "Sl. No:" << setw(15) << "Month" << setw(15) << "Name" << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 1 << setw(15) << "January" << setw(15) << "Abhilash" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 2 << setw(15) << "Februaury" << setw(15) << "Anandan" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 3 << setw(15) << "March" << setw(15) << "Abhilash" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 4 << setw(15) << "April" << setw(15) << "Anandan" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the output I get, the names of the months are not right justified.

```
Sl. No:          Month           Name

    1        January       Abhilash
    2      Februaury        Anandan
    3          March       Abhilash
    4          April        Anandan
```

What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Well this trick is aligning from left side what if we want to align from right side

Answer (score 7):

The string `Sl. No:` is 7 wide and you are trying to fit it into a 5 wide column. That pushes the first row over by 2 columns. Try making your first column 7 wide rather than 5 wide instead:

```
cout << setw(7) << "Sl. No:" << setw(15) << "Month" << setw(15) << "Name"
     << endl << endl;
cout << setw(7) << 1 << setw(15) << "January" << setw(15) << "Abhilash"
     << endl;
//...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you for reminding of the silly beginner mistakes that can be made. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to use setw, you have to count from the end of the output string, int, etc.  So when you say

```
 cout << setw(15) << "January";
```

It'll format 8 spaces in between since January is 7 characters. So in your example, you want to have

```
 cout << setw(23) << "January";
```

That obviously depends if you keep your first output of '1' in the same place.

Answer (score -2):

You can also use "\t" before `setw()` to make sure your not eating into the space.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << setw(5) << "Sl. No:" << setw(15) << "Month" << setw(15) << "Name" << endl << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 1 << "\t" << setw(15) << "January" << "\t" << setw(15) << "Abhilash" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 2 << "\t" << setw(15) << "Februaury" << "\t" << setw(15) << "Anandan" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 3 << "\t" << setw(15) << "March" << "\t" << setw(15) << "Abhilash" << endl;
    cout << setw(5) << 4 << "\t" << setw(15) << "April" << "\t" << setw(15) << "Anandan" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Oh you need to use spacing in front of the "month"

```
    "  month"
```

not

```
    "month"
```

the results will look like this

```
     Month
    January
```

you may have to adjust the amount of spacing you use.