# Finding the max lengths of strings to format a table output

Tags: c++, string, c++11, vector

I want to find the max length of specific attributes from a `vector` of `Person` objects.

Below is an example of a `Person` object:

```cpp
Person::Person(string first_name, string last_name, int the_age){
     first = first_name;
     last = last_name;
     age = the_age;
}
```

I have a `vector` that stores `Person` objects, and I must print all the people out in a table, like so:

```cpp
First Name  Last Name     Age
----------  ------------  ----
John        Cool-Johnson  15
Paul        Bob           1000
2 people
```

I need to find the max length of each attribute of a `Person` in order to grow each column according to the maximum length of `name` or `age`. How can I do this?

So far, I have tried lambdas using this code:

```cpp
unsigned int max_name = *max_element(generate(people.begin(),people.end(), [](Person a){return a.getFirstName()})).size();
```

But I am not sure if this even works at all.

I must use `<iomanip>`, but I have no clue how it works.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Your code looks fine.  What part of it is giving you a problem?  If it how to set the width of the columns, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679569/c-table-alignment-cout-and-iomanip

Comment: @Linus Did you consider that the titles themselves may be off if you resize the second and third columns?

Comment: I am confused about setw. Should it look like this: setw(max_name) to get the correct column sizes?

Comment: @Linus What is `generate()`? It can't be [`std::generate()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate), so it must be something else. But either way, [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) requires 2 iterators, which you are not providing to it. You can use `std::max_element()` to solve this issue, just not the way you have shown.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I found generate from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307168/how-to-fill-a-c-container-using-a-lambda-function 
will this not work? I am simply trying to create a new vector of the attributes from each person then finding the max length

Comment: @RemyLebeau is this a possibility: `vector<string> names = generate(people.begin(),people.end(), [](Person a){return a.getFirstName()});` then `unsigned int max_name = *max_element(names.begin(), names.end()).size();`

Comment: @Linus None of the `generate()` functions in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51307168/how-to-fill-a-c-container-using-a-lambda-function) match that syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of `std::max_element()` is wrong.  It takes 2 iterators for input, which you are not providing to it.  It would need to look more like this:

```cpp
auto max_name = max_element(
    people.begin(), people.end(),
    [](const Person &a, const Person &b){
        return a.getFirstName().size() < b.getFirstName().size();
    }
)->getFirstName().size();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/DG6bas)

Alternatively:

```cpp
vector<string> names;
names.reserve(people.size());

for(const Person &p : people) {
    names.push_back(p.getFirstName());
}

auto max_name = max_element(
    names.begin(), names.end(),
    [](const string &a, const string &b){
        return a.size() < b.size();
    }
)->size();
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ZUCG7Y)

However, since you will probably also want to do the same thing for the `Last Name` and `Age` columns, I would suggest simply looping though the `people` vector manually, keeping track of the max lengths as you go along, eg:

```cpp
string::size_type max_fname = 10;
string::size_type max_lname = 9;
string::size_type max_age = 3;

for(const Person &p : people)
{
    max_fname = max(max_fname, p.getFirstName().size());
    max_lname = max(max_lname, p.getLastName().size());
    max_age = max(max_age, to_string(p.getAge()).size());
}
```

Then you can output everything in a table, eg:

```cpp
cout << left << setfill(' ');
cout << setw(max_fname) << "First Name" << "  " << setw(max_lname) << "Last Name" << "  " << setw(max_age) << "Age" << "\n";
cout << setfill('-');
cout << setw(max_fname) << "" << "  " << setw(max_lname) << "" << "  " << setw(max_age) << "" << "\n";
cout << setfill(' ');

for(const Person &p : people)
{
    cout << setw(max_fname) << p.getFirstName() << "  " << setw(max_lname) << p.getLastName() << "  " << setw(max_age) << p.getAge() << "\n";
}

cout << people.size() << " people\n";
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/SsateY)